# what's the purpose/point of the REAL() Datatype in mysql?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, precision, numerical

what's the purpose/point of the REAL() Datatype in mysql? You have float,double and decimal which i understand but where does the "real" datatype come into it? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance ;-)

is real the same as float or double?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> MySQL treats `REAL` as a synonym for `DOUBLE`, unless the `REAL_AS_FLOAT` SQL mode is enabled.

Source: [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual - Numeric Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html)

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

> MySQL also treats REAL as a synonym for DOUBLE PRECISION (a nonstandard variation), unless the REAL_AS_FLOAT SQL mode is enabled.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 3):

REAL is just another name for DOUBLE PRECISION.